# How to print a text next to a line in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Line and Textblock in my xaml as follow:

```
 <Line X1="{Binding StartPoint.X}" Y1="{Binding StartPoint.Y}" X2="{Binding EndPoint.X}"
          Y2="{Binding EndPoint.Y}" Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}" />
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

The TextBlock shows the title of line (for example "Line 1").

The above XAML draw the lines on a canvas and work correctly, but it doesn't show the TextBlock next to line and in parallel to it.

How can I change this XAML code so the text be in the centre of line and parallel to it.

Comment: As usual: bind the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties of the TextBlock to appropriate view model properties.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that by using a `TextBlock` and nest inside of it the `Line` and the `TextBlock` you want to use. For example:

```
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="132" Height="45">
                <Line X1="10" Y1="20" X2="100" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </TextBlock>
```

The result of the above will be:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't put the line in parallel to text.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to solve your problem with a different approach

example below will render the line for given coordinates and will place a label next to it

I start by writing a class for LineData

```
class LineData : DependencyObject
{
    public Point P1
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(P1Property); }
        set { SetValue(P1Property, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for P1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty P1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("P1", typeof(Point), typeof(LineData), new PropertyMetadata(new Point(), (d, e) => (d as LineData).Update()));

    public Point P2
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(P2Property); }
        set { SetValue(P2Property, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for P1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty P2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("P2", typeof(Point), typeof(LineData), new PropertyMetadata(new Point(), (d, e) => (d as LineData).Update()));

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Label.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(LineData), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public double Length
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LengthProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Length.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Length", typeof(double), typeof(LineData), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public double TransformAngle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(TransformAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TransformAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TransformAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TransformAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TransformAngle", typeof(double), typeof(LineData), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public void Update()
    {
        //calculate angle
        double dy = P2.Y - P1.Y;
        double dx = P2.X - P1.X;
        double theta = Math.Atan2(dy, dx);
        theta *= 180 / Math.PI;
        TransformAngle = theta - 90;

        //calculate length
        double aSq = Math.Pow(P1.X - P2.X, 2); 
        double bSq = Math.Pow(P1.Y - P2.Y, 2);
        Length = Math.Sqrt(aSq + bSq);
    }
}
```

in this class i wrote logic to convert given point into angle and length which will be used in data template to render accordingly, Update method is called when any point is changed

here comes the xaml, here l: is namespace to the line data class

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=P1.X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=P1.Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding TransformAngle}"/>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Line Y2="{Binding Length}" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <l:LineData Label="Line 1" P1="100,100" P2="135,150"/>
        <l:LineData Label="Line 2" P1="150,150" P2="235,50"/>
    </ItemsControl>
```

- i used the canvas as panel of the items control
- placed the item at the correct place by binding canvas.left and canvas.top to point one of the line data in style of ContentPresenter
- created a data template with a grid, label and line
- set the y2 of line as length of line data leaving all other points to be 0
- set the label in textbox
- rotated the grid based on the angle

it's done, result of the sample

[image: result]

since I was not sure what is actually meant by parallel to you I assumed a label which is horizontal when line is vertical (so perpendicular to line)

if you want both horizontally parallel then apply a render transform to your textblock too

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="16,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
```

[image: horizontally parallel]

you may also bind the items control to a observable collection of line data and binding will do the rest.

**Alternative horizontally parallel approach**

```
    public void Update()
    {
        double dy = P2.Y - P1.Y;
        double dx = P2.X - P1.X;
        double theta = Math.Atan2(dy, dx);
        theta *= 180 / Math.PI;
        TransformAngle = theta; //remove the 90 degree vertial adjustment

        double aSq = Math.Pow(P1.X - P2.X, 2);
        double bSq = Math.Pow(P1.Y - P2.Y, 2);
        Length = Math.Sqrt(aSq + bSq);
    }

<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding TransformAngle}"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
        <Line X2="{Binding Length}" Grid.Row="1" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

- removed vertical adjustment in calculation
- using Length property for line's X2
- removed margin adjustments from textblock

result is bit cleaner approach without adjustments